# I'm comparing user input with MySQL database but I'm getting wrong result

Tags: php

I'm writing a code to compare user input with the database. I want the code display "is phishing" when the user input a word that already exist on the database.

```
<?php
    include 'backend.php';
            $userinput = $_POST['userinput'];    
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            
              $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    
                if($userinput==isset($row['keywords']))
                {
                    echo "is phishing";
                }else{
                    echo "is legitimate";
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `isset()` function returns a boolean value that indicates if the parameter you provided `is set` or not. i.e. The parameter is not `null` or declared and never initialized.

To search for a value in an array you need to use the `in_array()` function, as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Therefore your code should be:

```
if(in_array($userinput, $row['keywords']))
{
    echo "is phishing";
}else{
    echo "is legitimate";
}
```

Be aware that `in_array()` IS case-sensitive. In that case:

```
$values = ["StackOverflow"];

in_array("StackOverflow", $values);  //true
in_array("stackoverflow", $values);  //false
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use isset function, it returns true/false, you are compairing a variable to a boolean value, if that data coming from data that means it already set, just remove isset function